# extraer texto de una pagina externa js/php

Tags: php, javascript, html

que tal ando buscando la forma por la cual pueda extraer datos  de una pagina externa
me explico

aqui esta la api que estoy usando en php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesito es traerme ese pequeño frgamento que dice `<code>200</code>`
pero como no es mia la web no se como traermelo o que metodo usar ya que lo insertare a mi base de datos entonces necesito el puro frgamento del estatus estoy programando en php, js, ajax, mysql etc

mi codigo el cual solo guarda en mi base de datos me manda a la api pero no me permite guardar el code que necesito en mi base de datos

```
<?php
$mensaje=!empty($_POST['mensaje']) ? $_POST['mensaje'] : NULL;
$numero=!empty($_POST['numero']) ? $_POST['numero'] : NULL;
session_start();
  
   include("configuracion.php");
   $fecha= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error connecting to database. ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
$mensaje=!empty($_POST['mensaje']) ? $_POST['mensaje'] : NULL;
$numero=!empty($_POST['numero']) ? $_POST['numero'] : NULL;

$sql="INSERT INTO enviados (mensaje, numero,fecha) 
VALUES  ('$mensaje','$numero', '$fecha')";

$data = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if($data)
{
  echo'
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Guardado Exitosamente!");
    window.location.href="admin.php";
    </script>';
    header("Location: https://b2c.marcatel.com.mx/MarcatelSMSWCF/ServicioInsertarSMS.svc/InsertaMensajes_xl_Corto/$mensaje/$numero/PROGRAMADOR/Cmg12345/nueva/1/Auxiliar/0");
exit;
}else{
  echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: VALE lo tengo la edito

Comment: El problema es que estás redirigiendo y deberías realizar una petición para capturar los datos. Desde PHP puedes usar [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php) o, desde javascript, una petición AJAX.

Comment: y ese como se implements

Comment: Tu URL parece ser un Servicio Web, ahora me pregunto, ¿por qué quieres pasar por PHP cuando podrías obtener/leer/mostrar la respuesta directamente en el cliente usando Ajax, sin tener que pasar por PHP para hacer lo mismo y encima convertirlo  a otro tipo/formato de respuesta gastando tiempo y recursos y exponiéndote a posibles errores de conversión? En este caso lo mejor sería devolver al cliente **únicamente** los valores de `$mensaje` y de `$numero` y usarlos para lanzar **desde el cliente** la petición al Servicio Web. No hay niguna necesidad de sobrecargar al servidor como lo haces.

Answer (score 0):

El código lo sacas en PHP así:

```php
$url = 'https://b2c.marcatel.com.mx/MarcatelSMSWCF/ServicioInsertarSMS.svc/InsertaMensajes_xl_Corto/asdf/1/PROGRAMADOR/Cmg12345/nueva/1/Auxiliar/0';
$contenido = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($contenido);
$codigo = (string) $xml->code[0];
var_dump($codigo); // 200

$url = 'https://b2c.marcatel.com.mx/MarcatelSMSWCF/ServicioInsertarSMS.svc/InsertaMensajes_xl_Corto/asdf/1/INGENIERO/Cmg12345/nueva/1/Auxiliar/0';
$contenido = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($contenido);
$codigo = (string) $xml->code[0];
var_dump($codigo); // 437
```